# .innerHTML Not Displaying While Using a For Loop

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a script that will allow users to input numbers into a screen, add them to an array and then print the values on an innerHTML element.

However, when I attempt to use it in a for loop, nothing is printing out and it goes to a new page where the only thing displayed is the first number entered.

I am new at JavaScript and might be doing it incorrectly. Please let me know!

Thanks in advance

```js
var a = [];

var count = 0;

function addNum() {
  a[count] = document.getElementById('input').value;
  count++;
}

function printValues() {
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    document.write(a[i], " ").innerHTML = array;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="addNum();" value="Add Number">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="printValues();" value="Print Numbers">
<p>
  <a id="array"></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. It will remove everything else that was on your page. See [this note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) on MDN: `Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.`

Comment: I'm not sure what the `addNum()` function is intended to do. I looks like you may want to [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the value into an array.

Comment: @MattBurland What do you suggest then? I'm new to this

Comment: Not sure where you learned that syntax for document.write, but that is not right.

Comment: @showdev I am just playing with Arrays at the same time to get the hang of it

Comment: @epascarello What is wrong with it?

Comment: It is not valid. `document.getElementById("array").innerHTML = "Your Output";`

Comment: Use DOM manipulation. Select an element on your page and set it's content to what you want. You should be able to find plenty of tutorials.

Comment: @epascarello Okay I see it now, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write):

> Note: as document.write writes to the document stream, calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open which will clear the document.

So your problem is caused by `document.write`. Once you `write` to your already loaded document, everything else is thrown away, including your javascript. (You had other problems too with just how you were using it, but this is the main problem).

You have an element with the id `array`, which I assume is where you want to put your numbers. So you need to get that element with `getElementById` and then set its `innerHTML`. You can use `array.join` to avoid the loop.

```js
var a = [];

var count = 0;

function addNum() {
  a[count] = document.getElementById('input').value;
  count++;
}

function printValues() {
  document.getElementById('array').innerHTML = a.join(",");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="addNum();" value="Add Number">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="printValues();" value="Print Numbers">
<p>
  <a id="array"></a>
</p>
```

A couple of other things you should look at. After adding a number in `addNum`, you should probably clear the text box by setting the `value` to null. Secondly, it's preferred to add event handlers in code rather than in your HTML.

Comment: I'm assuming the .join method is a built in one to arrays that takes the character parameter that splits the indexes?

Comment: @NicholasDry: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) is a wonderful resource. You should become familiar with it. It's often the first result when you search for a javascript method (if you see W3 Schools instead, skip that and go down to the MDN link).

Comment: Okay awesome, I had been looking at W3, but I will take a look at MDN. thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
function printValues() {
    var strValues='';  // Initialize a temporary variable 

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      strValues += a[i] + ' ';            
    }
    document.write(strValues); //Writting variable to document.
}
```

In the above example we have create a temporary variable and sets the default value to blank. Then in for loop we concatenate the array value to variable using **+=** sign.

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful.

Comment: The purpose is to set the values to a string value and then print that string right?

Comment: I added some explanation so that you can understand what the above code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is not the correct way of setting stuff up in `innerHTML` . Also, you are not retaining the values to be printed on to the screen. Everytime , you click on print the new value inputted by the user is just getting passed and the old value is getting replaced with the new one . Here the variable `valueToBePrinted` will always remember the last value that was inputted as it concatenates all the inputted values to it, once the user is done with his/her input .

Look at the following piece of code :

```
var a = [];
var count = 0;

function addNum() {

    a[count] = document.getElementById('input').value;
    console.log(a[count]);
    count++;
}

function printValues() {
    var valueToBePrinted='';
    for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
      valueToBePrinted += a[i] + ' ';
      console.log(valueToBePrinted)
      document.getElementById('array').innerHTML =valueToBePrinted;
    }
}
```

Also , look at the result in the Fiddle here : **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7dcvnkxs/)**

Answer (score 0):

The statement "document.write(a[i], " ").innerHTML = array;" is wrong.
There is no variable named array declared in the code.

The correct form to print all the numbers using document.write is,

```
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
     document.write(a[i] + " ");
}
```

If you need sum of all input numbers and the print the sum, then you can simply sum it up in a variable as you click addNumber button as,

```
var total = 0;
function addNum() {
    total += Number(document.getElementById('input').value);
}

function printValues() {
    document.write(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You typically would not use a "count" variable to add items to an array but would instead push to the array however I kept it in case you needed it otherwise.
- You would as others noted not do a document.write to an element but instead use the innerHTML and replace or append to that.
- Odd also that you are putting the innerHTML in a link `<a />` element but since that is what you are using I will reproduce that.
- IF you do want to use these as number (integers?) you would want to parse them with `parseInt(string, radix);` or parsefloat.
- You did not have `i` set as a variable object so I did that here

Slightly reworked code here:

```
var a = [];

var count = 0;

function addNum() {
    a.push(parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value, 10));
    count++;
}

function printValues() {
    var i;
    var myValues = "";
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        myValues = myValues + a[i] + " ";
    }
    var element = document.getElementById("array");
    element.innerHTML = myValues;
}
```

Here is the code reproduced as a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/coffw8tg/